# Nested JSON object data with dimple.js chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nested, dimple.js

I need help to flatten my json data which is in nested format. I have try few things that I find in S/O but didnt help much. I spend so much time creating my chart with static data, I didn't know I would get my data in this format. Any help will be much  appreciated! I am using dimple vertical stack var

```
 {
  "head": {
    "vars": [ "Country" , "City" , "County" , "Fiscal_Year" , "Fiscal_Qtr" , "Start_Period" , "End_Period" , "Extract_Date" ,  "AA" , "BB" , "CC" , "DD" , "EE" , "FF" , "GG" , "HH" , "II" , "JJ" , "KK" , "LL" , "MM" , "NN" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "Country": {  "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "United States" } ,
        "City": {  "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "New York" } ,
        "County": {  "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "Manhattan" } ,
        "Fiscal_Year": {  "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "2014" } ,
        "Fiscal_Qtr": { "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "1" } ,
        "Start_Period": { "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "2014-10-01" } ,
        "End_Period": {  "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "2014-12-31" } ,
        "Extract_Date": {"type": "typed-literal" , "value": "2015-01-01" } ,
        "AA": {  "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "0.549" } ,
        "BB": { "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "0.1526" } ,
        "CC": {  "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "0.0258" } ,
        "DD": { "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "0.047400000000000005" } ,
        "EE": { "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "0.21780000000000002" } ,
        "FF": {"type": "typed-literal" , "value": "0.0074" } ,
        "GG": { "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "0.615" } ,
        "HH": { "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "0.507" } ,
        "II": { "type": "literal" , "value": "--" } ,
        "JJ": {"type": "typed-literal" , "value": "0.113" } ,
        "KK": {  "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "0.026" } ,
        "LL": { "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "0.034" } ,
        "MM": { "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "0.318" } ,
        "NN": { "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "0.002" }
      }
```

I am looking for output for something like this:

```
    [
{"Country": "United States"},
{"City": "New York"},
{"County": "Manhattan"},
{"Fiscal_Year": "2014"},
{"Start_Period": "2014-10-01"},
{"End_Period": "2014-12-32"},
{"Extract_Date": "2015-01-01" },
{"AA": "0.549" },
{"BB": "0.1526" },
{"CC": "0.0258" },
{"DD": "0.047400000000000005" },
{"EE":  "0.21780000000000002" },
{"FF": "0.0074" },
{"GG":  "0.615" },
{"HH":  "0.507" },
{"II":  "--" },
{"JJ":  "0.113" },
{"KK":  "0.026" },
{"LL":  "0.034" },
{"MM":  "0.318" },
{"NN":  "0.002" }
]
```

Comment: You should provide an example of what you want that data to be turned into

Comment: @meetamit I just updated with the prefer output I am looking for. sorry for not putting that first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript's `Object.keys()` takes an object (eg `{foo: 1, bar: 2}`) and returns an array of that object's keys `["foo", "bar"]`.

Using that, you can convert you object like this:

```
data.results.bindings.map(function(original) {
  var converted = {};
  Object.keys(original)
    .forEach(function(key) {
      converted[key] = original[key].value;
    });
  return converted;
})
```

Alternatively, the same thing can be achieved using `reduce`.

```
data.results.bindings.map(function(original) {
  return Object.keys(original)
    .reduce(function(converted, key) {
      converted[key] = original[key].value;
      return converted;
    }, {});
})
```

There's not much more benefit of one way over the other, except that the 2nd option doesn't rely on defining the `var converted`, making more "inline-ish", which makes it more readable (at least in some circles).

Comment: Thank you this gave me the following output I want it. However; I didn't get my chart working as I want to. I was wondering if I can make another output and can you help me again please? Thank you!

Comment: Sure man, go ahead. But it's probably in your best interest to post it as a separate question — in case someone else gets to it before me — and then comment again here with a link to the question, and I'll take a look.